# How to use the mongodb Timestamp type with mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Mongodb has a specific Timestamp type - can anyone tell me how to use this when I am using a mongoose schema?

Comment: Read the first comment on this recent [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45694476/how-to-store-a-full-date-format-in-mongodb).

Comment: Thanks Mikey but that's about dates the Timestamp is a 64 mongodb bit structure.