# How to store a full date format in mongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to save data in mongoDB database, 
I am send a full date format like this "`Wednesday March 25 2015`" for example,
When I make a http call to save some data including the date, the date format that actually being saved in mongoDB is  UTC datetime like this: '`2016-05-18T16:00:00Z`',
How can I store the full date format in the databse?

my code for saving the data including the date is:

```
app.post('/postDiary', authenticate, (req, res) => {

var diary = new Diary ({
    headacheLevel: req.body.headacheLevel,
    headacheSide: req.body.headacheSide,
    nausea: req.body.nausea,
    aura: req.body.aura,
    photophobia: req.body.photophobia,
    phonophobia: req.body.phonophobia,
    date: new Date(req.body.date),
    location: req.body.location,
    weather: req.body.weather,
    _creator: req.user._id
});

   diary.save().then( (diary) => {
       res.send(diary);
   }, (err) => {
       res.status(400).send(err);
   });
});
```

and the part of date in my schema is this:

```
 date: {
    type: Date,
    default: new Date()
},
```

Hope you can help me with that, Thank you.

Comment: Mongodb save date format in utc only if you want save date format in string then use string for mongodb . If you want to use as you want you can convert that in application end. Use moment or date libaray to do so.

Comment: The behavior you're seeing of storing it as a UTC date is likely what you want as that enables its use in aggregation operations to do things like group by month. Your app then needs to understand that only the date portion of the stored UTC timestamp is relevant and you format it for display however you wish.